# why doesn't wolfram alpha evaluate this integral?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

i am trying to compute the integral given below using [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=$%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Csqrt2%7D%5Csin%5E%7B-1%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B2-x%5E2%7D%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright)dx$)
$$\int_0^{\sqrt2}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{2}\right)dx$$
However it can be solved by numerical method but i don't know why Wolfram alpha doesn't compute it. could somebody explain or help me solve this integral? thank u very much

Comment: Because Wolfram alpha has been made up by people and those people don't know how to compute it?

Comment: @HandeBruijn Wolfram Mathematica computes the integral just fine.

Comment: it can be solved by using numerical method.

Comment: Mathematica gives a nice closed form $2\pi^{3/2} / \Gamma(\frac{1}{4})^2$, though I have no idea why (without using elliptic functions).

Comment: It does compute the integral if you don't use LaTeX formatting https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sin%5E(-1)(sqrt(2-x%5E2)%2F2)+from+0+to+sqrt(2)

Comment: @SangchulLee no elliptic integrals are necessary it is all quite straightforward please see my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most direct way of calculating this integral starts as already explained by @Claude Leibovici: We integrate by parts and observe that the boundary term vanishs, so we are down to

$$
I=\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}dx\frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{1-(x^4/4)}}
$$

now setting $r=x^4/4$ we obtain

$$
I=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{1}dr\frac{1}{r^{1/4}(1-r)^{1/2}}
$$

this integrals equals  [an representation of the Eulerian Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) which, may in turn be expressed in terms of Gamma functions

$$
I=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(3/4)}{\Gamma(5/4)}
$$

using Gamma duplication as well as $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$ this boils down to

> $$
> I=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\frac{4 \sqrt{2}\pi^{3/2}}{\Gamma(1/4)^2}=\frac{2\pi^{3/2}}{\Gamma(1/4)^2}
> $$

as expected

Comment: thank you for the help but please tell me how to find out the value of $\Gamma(\frac 14)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_constant 
you might enjoy this wikipedia entry

Comment: please tell me how you reduced $\Gamma(\frac34)$ to $\Gamma(\frac14)$ from second to last step?

Comment: you can relate both values by the gamma duplication theorem

Comment: please provide a helpful link to go through the gamma duplication theorem

Comment: just use google, you will find plenty of good references

Answer (score 3):

I do not know why  Wolfram alpha does not compute this integral.

Let use consider the antiderivative $$I=\int\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{2}\right)dx$$ Integrating by parts lead to $$I=x \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{2}\right)+\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^4}}dx$$ The second term involves [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) $$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^4}}dx=\sqrt{2} \left(E\left(\left.\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|-1\right)-F\left(\left.\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|-1\right)\right)$$ Concerning the definite integral, the first term cancels because of the given bounds  and $$J=\int_0^t\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^4}}dx=\sqrt{2} \left(E\left(\left.\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|-1\right)-F\left(\left.\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|-1\right)\right)$$ which tends to $$\sqrt{2} \left(E(-1)-K(-1)\right)$$ when $t \to \sqrt{2}$. In fact this can simplify to $$\frac{2 \pi ^{3/2}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}\approx 0.847213$$

Comment: Alpha actually does compute it given proper input. +1 for writing down solution.

Comment: No offense, but don't you think elliptic integrals are a bit too much here? given the limits of integration you can straightforwardly transform, after the integration by parts, it into an euler beta like expression by using $r=x^4/4$

Comment: @tired. You are right and may I confess that I upvoted your good answer ? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

WolframAlpha isn't really that good at reading $\TeX$; you need to [simplify the input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Esqrt(2)+sin%5E(-1)(sqrt(2-x%5E2)%2F2)dx&x=0&y=0) a bit.

Comment: Actually, your input is not what is intended. It should be [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?x=0&y=0&i=int_0%5Esqrt+2++arcsin(sqrt+(2-x%5E2)+%2F2)+dx#875177828184307699).

Comment: @Ennar You mean `arcsin` instead of `sin^(-1)`? WA handles that. Actually, note that in your link, WA actually converts back to $\sin^{-1}$. Also, you still get $\frac{2\pi^{3/2}}{\Gamma(1/4)^2}$

Comment: No, arcsin/sin^{-1} is irrelevant. What you link gives is: "Using closest Wolfram|Alpha interpretation: -1 sqrt 2-x^2 /2" i.e. it is parsed completely wrong way by alpha.

Comment: @Ennar When I click my link, I get [this result](http://i.imgur.com/7oLmVs4.png), which to me looks like it's parsed correctly. True, it first gets some strange complex value, then corrects it, but that's the same for yours.

Comment: I'm getting [this](http://imgur.com/Fxxa4fM), and have no idea what is going on...

Comment: @Ennar It looks like all the parentheses disappear when you click the link. This is really strange. It works fine both on my computer and on my phone.